# Magento 2 fotorama slider show more than 1 image at a time

Tags: product, magento-2.1, product-view, slider, fotorama-slider

I want to show 3 product images at a time on Product detail page.

Here is the example image:
[image]

But fotorama image only show 1 image at a time on slider.
It doesn't have `slides` or `items` options to set slides of slider view.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible out the box with fotorama, not based off the Github issues or available options anyway.